# How to pass a null value in the clancats hydrahon update()?

Tags: php

I need to pass a null value for a database column, according to the code below:

```
$birthdate = null;

User::update()
->set('name', $name)
->set('email', $email)
->set('birthdate', $birthdate)                
->where('id', $id)
->execute();
```

But the error is generated:

[image]

How to do this ?

**Note: The update is a method of clancats hydrahon.**

I believe that the problem occurs in that part of the library code.

```
public function set($param1, $param2 = null)
{
// do nothing if we get nothing
if (empty($param1))
{
   return $this;
}
        
// when param 2 is not null we assume that only one set is passed
// like: set( 'name', 'Lu' ); instead of set( array( 'name' => 'Lu' ) );
if ( !is_null( $param2 ) )
{
   $param1 = array( $param1 => $param2 );
}
        
// merge the new values with the existing ones.
$this->values = array_merge( $this->values, $param1 ); 
        
// return self so we can continue running the next function
return $this;
}
```

Comment: seems to me a peculiarity of this library.

Comment: I added part of the lib code that I believe is the reason for the error.

Comment: I didn't understand. When I pass a date string it works.

Comment: can you share the values of param1 and param2 when the error is occuring ?

Comment: $param1 Array ( ). $param2 nameGato Schrödingeremailgatoschrodinger@gmail.combirthdate

Comment: When your $param1 is an empty array, then it does not reach to the array_merge function, it should return according to your code, your statement is conflicting

Comment: As well ? I'm using the library code. So does lib not support null in its update() method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all; **Never ever changes the files in the vendor directories.**
Vendor directories should not be versionned in your project and any changes will not be available in production or for someone else.

As answer; I think using an array should works. And also because it's wrote in comment

> // when param 2 is not null we assume that only one set is passed
> // like: set( 'name', 'Lu' ); instead of **set( array( 'name' => 'Lu' ) );**

```php
$birthdate = null;

User::update()
->set('name', $name)
->set('email', $email)
->set(['birthdate' => $birthdate]) // like this               
->where('id', $id)
->execute();
```

**Reason**

```php
if (empty($param1)) { // false: because it's not empty. We pass on
   return $this;
}
```

```php
if ( !is_null( $param2 ) ) { // false: because it IS null. We pass on
   $param1 = array( $param1 => $param2 );
}
```

At this point we have `$param1 = ['birthdate' => null]` and `$param2 = null`
But this time, we don't have a string. We have an array.

```php
 // $this->values = array_merge( [], ['birthdate' => null] ); 
    $this->values = array_merge( $this->values, $param1 );
```

---

Going further, I think you can even do like this

```php
User::update()
->set([
    'name'      => $name,
    'email'     => $email,
    'birthdate' => $birthdate,
 ])             
->execute();
```

Comment: An error has now occurred in another file: "Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp64\www\devsbook\core\Model.php on line 27". That would be in that code
: https://paste.laravel.io/9d01fdca-afd0-4596-a0ab-759db4cda2f4

Comment: I don't know what else to do. This was supposed to be a simple thing

Comment: What the content of the variables ? The line you mentioned `$statement->execute($queryParameters);` [takes an array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) if you're using PDOStatement. The error *Array to string conversion* makes no sense for this line

Comment: I'm starting to seriously think about doing an improvisation (I don't know what the correct English word would be).

Comment: please make a `var_dump($variable);` and `die;` Based on the line 52, it looks like it happens *before* the update with something unrelated.

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand where I would have to put this var_dump

Comment: Line 19. Before `$statement = $connection->prepare($queryString);` `var_dump($queryString);` ``var_dump($queryParameters);`.

Comment: *Array to string conversion* Is most often related when you try to echo an array like this `echo $myArray;` instead of `echo $myArray['key']`. Are you certain you didn't add something that could cause that somewhere?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: queryString in C:\wamp64\www\devsbook\core\Model.php on line 19... Notice: Undefined variable: queryParameters in C:\wamp64\www\devsbook\core\Model.php on line 20

Comment: Line 19 of the link you gave me

Comment: C:\wamp64\www\devsbook\core\Model.php:20:null

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes. I'm starting my career.

Comment: Does the values are updated in the database though?

Comment: No. Before I added the set('birthdate', ['birthdate' => $ birthdate]) it updated. It just wouldn't update if I sent the birthdate as null.

Comment: Like this `->set(['birthdate' => $birthdate])`

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much. You helped me a lot. All the best for you.

Comment: Did you edit the answer or did I really copy it wrong?

Comment: Brazil now loves you :)

Comment: Hahaha best wishes from Switzerland 

Comment: If you want you can answer here too: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/476103/como-passar-um-valor-null-no-m%c3%a9todo-update-do-clancats-hydrahon

Comment: Can you help me with that question ?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64356022/how-to-pass-values-by-bind-to-the-same-suffix-that-is-repeated-in-the-querie

Answer (score 1):

This is because you pass `null` as `$birthdate`. That code is designed for these inputs:

```
$param1 = 'name';
$param2 = 'value';
```

or an array.

```
$param1 = [ 'name' => 'value' ];
$param2 = null;
```

You must send something as a value.

You should do it either

```
User::update()
->set('name', $name)
->set('email', $email)
->where('id', $id)
->execute();
```

or

```
$birthdate = 'YYYY-MM-DD'; //some date, can't be null

User::update()
->set('name', $name)
->set('email', $email)
->set('birthdate', $birthdate)                
->where('id', $id)
->execute();
```

or

```
$params = [
     'name' => $name,
     'email' => $email
];

if(!is_null($birthdate)) {
    $params['birthdate'] = $birthdate;
}

User::update()
->set($params)              
->where('id', $id)
->execute();
```

Comment: But I did not understand. Wouldn't Null be a value? How would I get my code to work?

Comment: I edited my answer. I hope it clarifies your doubts.

Comment: I appreciate the idea. However, this does not solve the null problem. That doesn't seem to be very feasible, does it?

Comment: You can define `$birthdate` as empty string `''`, so then your code will work, but field birthdate will be cleared in database.

Comment: You have many solutions. It depends exactly what do you need field birthdate for.

Comment: Empty string does not work. I've tried to pass. I need the user to be able to inform the date of birth field, but he can stop informing if he wants to.

Comment: I added a new way. And there plenty of other methods how you can implement it. You only must choose it and if `$birthdate` is null you can't set that field in database.

Comment: Your answer had also been useful to me. I only realized it now. I gave an upvote. Thank you